# How to convert list of polygon objects to 2D list of coords with Python

Tags: python, list, polygon, points

I have a list of polygon objects:

```
[shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7efa3099f210, 
 shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7efa3099f5d0, 
 shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7efa30a01410]
```

I would like to convert these back into a list of 2D coordinates like this:

```
[[(59.019498746806114, -45.665396889176236), 
  (59.94899586119081, -45.18051792326192), 
  (60.264519944473435, -43.49720173548366), 
  (63.13914992079595, -41.75713765132456)], 
 [(65.27046115508618, -38.81009751714569), 
  (66.87400474798349, -35.32763756915183), 
  (66.59651348548812, -34.479633238363796), 
  (64.08620000264494, -34.508862817833695)], 
 [(62.967585829885984, -39.02682594501325), 
  (58.84847235610258, -41.12579914422148), 
  (57.972105870186965, -45.614782988871184), 
  (59.019498746806114, -45.665396889176236)]]
```

I realize from shapely.geometry import Polygon converts the coordinates into a polygon, however I am trying to do the opposite.

Any advice on how to go about this using Python?

Comment: `[polygon.exterior.coords for polygon in polygons]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure on API, but try

```
coords = [list(poly.exterior.coords) for poly in poly_list]
```